# cython - how to define a memory view with sizes

Tags: python, cython

This may be quite a silly question. Suppose I have a code in Cython that uses MemoryViews as follows:

```
cdef extern from 'math.h' nogil:
    float NAN
...

cdef double[:] stat_vec(double[:] x, double m, char* stat_func):
    cdef:
        vector_ptr stat_func_ptr = stat_switch(stat_func)
        double[:] y = x.copy()
    y[:] = NAN
    ... < do_something_with_elements_of_x_and_populate_elements_of_y >
    return y
```

The code above takes a MemoryView `x` and returns another MemoryView `y` of the same size as `x`.

To define the size of `y`, I am using a 2-step approach:

1. first I assign `y` to `x.copy()` (where I think `y` gets it size)
2. then I assign `y` to `NAN`.

I'm unable to convert this current function to `nogil` because of the `x.copy()` statement. Is there a better alternative way to initialize `y` with the size / shape of `x` and initial values of `NAN` ?

Comment: `y = np.empty(x.shape);y[:] = np.NAN`?

Comment: any way to avoid using `np` function. I want to convert it into a `nogil` function so that in the future I can parallelize it

Comment: have you lookee here http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/memoryviews.html

Comment: yes, didn't quite get it. do I need to use `malloc` and then `free`?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to convert your function to `nogil`, would be to allocate the `y` array outside of the function, and reinitialize it at every function call.

```
cdef double[::] stat_vec(double[::] x, double m, char* stat_func, double[::] y) nogil:

    cdef long i, n
    n = x.shape[0]
    for i in range(n):
        y[i] = x[i]
    # do other calculations
```

This is also preferable performance wise, so you don't spend time allocating/deallocating your `y` array, if `stat_vec` is called multiple times.